# Cross join within a dataframe given a time range pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am having a dataframe as below:

```
ID    GROUP   DATE_MIN               DATE_MAX
1     L1      02/12/2022 6:30AM      02/12/2022 6:35AM
2     L1      02/12/2022 6:33AM      02/12/2022 6:40AM
3     L1      02/12/2022 6:37AM      02/12/2022 6:40AM
4     L2      02/12/2022 7:30AM      02/12/2022 7:35AM
5     L2      02/12/2022 7:33AM      02/12/2022 7:35AM
6     L2      02/12/2022 7:34AM      02/12/2022 7:38AM
```

I wanted to count the number of rows per group (GROUP column) between the time range(DATE_MIN, DATE_MAX)
output expected is

```
ID    GROUP   DATE_MIN               DATE_MAX                NumberOfRows
1     L1      02/12/2022 6:30AM      02/12/2022 6:35AM        2 <<because of ID 1 and 2>>
2     L1      02/12/2022 6:33AM      02/12/2022 6:40AM        3 <<because of ID 1, 2 and 3>>
3     L1      02/12/2022 6:37AM      02/12/2022 6:40AM        2 <<because of ID 3 and 2>>
4     L2      02/12/2022 7:30AM      02/12/2022 7:35AM        1 << because of 4 only>>
5     L2      02/12/2022 7:36AM      02/12/2022 7:40AM        2 <<because of 5 and 6>>
6     L2      02/12/2022 7:37AM      02/12/2022 7:40AM        2 <<because of 5 and 6>>
```

Comment: how many rows do you have?

Comment: The number of rows is nearly 6 digits ...

Comment: can you update your example to add another group? The logic is not fully clear, so if possible add a example that would be different than the current group

Comment: Done with new groups as well

Comment: @mozway +1. Perhaps it's somethig like "time interval defined by `range(DATE_MIN, DATE_MAX)` includes any slice of all other time intervals"

Comment: Shouldn't ID 2's count be 3? It also overlaps 1

Comment: Oops sorry corrected

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your groups are not huge (as this solution is building a square matrix per group), you can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
def count(g):
    # convert to datetime arrays
    d_min = pd.to_datetime(g['DATE_MIN']).to_numpy()
    d_max = pd.to_datetime(g['DATE_MAX']).to_numpy()
    # build the square comparisons to see if the intervals overlap
    # aggregate as sum
    return pd.Series((  (d_min[:,None]<=d_max)
                      & (d_max[:,None]>=d_min)
                     ).sum(axis=0),
                     index=g.index)

df['NumberOfRows'] = df.groupby('GROUP', group_keys=False).apply(count)
```

*NB. efficiency might be better if you initially convert the dates to datetime and remove the conversion from the function.*

Output:

```
   ID GROUP           DATE_MIN           DATE_MAX  NumberOfRows
0   1    L1  02/12/2022 6:30AM  02/12/2022 6:35AM             2
1   2    L1  02/12/2022 6:33AM  02/12/2022 6:40AM             3
2   3    L1  02/12/2022 6:37AM  02/12/2022 6:40AM             2
3   4    L2  02/12/2022 7:30AM  02/12/2022 7:35AM             1
4   5    L2  02/12/2022 7:36AM  02/12/2022 7:40AM             2
5   6    L2  02/12/2022 7:37AM  02/12/2022 7:40AM             2
```

Comment: I am getting ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column NumberOfRows

Comment: Can you try `df.groupby('GROUP', group_keys=False).apply(count).to_numpy()`? If this doesn't work, please provide your pandas version and a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

df['NumberOfRows'] = df.groupby('GROUP')['DATE_MIN'].transform(lambda x: x.between(df['DATE_MIN'], df['DATE_MAX']).sum())
print(df)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).